# searching a field containing white spaces in solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, fuzzy-search

I have indexed the word `aaa bbb cccddd` into Solr and if my query is `aaabb ccc d` how to get it matched with my indexed word.

I tried it with ~ and *, but I'm not able to get an exact match.

I also tried `<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>` in managed-schema file of solr-6.6.1

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/> -->
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: What you have done there will not work out good at all. You are running an NGram for Index and a Standard for Query time that does not fit well. Not at all for your cause.

Comment: Aside from this, what you are looking for is a "Phrase Query", have a read here: http://yonik.com/solr/query-syntax/